# Migration Task stuck. How to cancel

Tags: parse-platform

Now I am trying to migrate parse DB to mongo lab. My migration is stuck at Copy Snapshot. Clicking stop migration is not working. What do we do ? I looked at developer tool reqs in chrome. 
The GET status look like

```
curl 'https://parse.com/apps/appname/migrations' -X GET -H '_parse_session=XXXX'  -H 'Origin: https://dashboard.parse.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'X-CSRF-Token: YYYY' --compressed
```

Now I tried to run it with

```
-X DELETE.
```

But it is not working. Any idea how we can restart it ?

Comment: Having the same with a test parse app (with just 2 rows of data in 1 class) migrating to a test MongoDB server hosted on DigitalOcean. Not had any luck making the migration feature work at all. And since I can't cancel the migration I can't attempt to restart it.

Comment: Also tried with Mongolab. Tried with several apps. All of them stuck.

Comment: A related post can be seen here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/tPLTxNUf8Uo

Comment: Can consider an alternative solution too for the migration strategy, where migrating over to Couchbase and using Couchbase Mobile may be better overall.  I wrote up part 1 of a blog here:  

http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/january/migration-from-parse-to-couchbase

Comment: Probably. But it requires rewriting all aspects of App. May be ok for people who are starting out. But definitely not for people who have already written the app.

Comment: Any updates on this ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can contact parse directly to get help with your specific migration using the job id:

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/42

> We discussed this here and basically in order to deal with migration
>   issues, we need you to individually report a bug through
>   parse.com/help. This allows each of you to get individual support,
>   from a team who can escalate issues, and for us to be able to ask up
>   front for specific information which will help us handle your issue.
>   We're exposing the 'job id' for the migration in the UI, and that is
>   something you should provide if you're having a problem.
>
> Going to close this issue. For problems involving migration, or any
>   issues not specific to parse-server, please visit
>   https://parse.com/help and find the bug icon / "Something wrong?"
>   section to start the bug reporting flow.